# SSRS: Get values from a particular row of DataSet?

Tags: reporting-services

My dataset currently has 12 rows of data. Each representing data for a month. I would like to have variance of a column between to rows, the rows being last & last but one i.e., latest month and previous month's data.
It could have been simple if I were to work on tablix but thats not the case. I want those values for a textbox.

Any ideas on it anyone?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I hope you are using SSRS 2008R2:

R2 introduced the [Lookup function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx) that is perfect for this scenario.

```
=Lookup( Fields!ProductUID.Value ,Fields!ProductID.Value,Fields!Price.Value,"PriceDataSet")
```

The Lookup function above will evaluate the first parameter ("Fields!ProductUID.Value") in the current dataset, then look for a matching value in the field specified in the second parameter ("Fields!ProductID.Value") in the dataset specified in the fourth parameter. The value of the third parameter is then evaluated in that row of the dataset and returned.

A little convoluted, but very helpful.

In your case, you can use this in a textbox with a calculated a static number:

```
=Lookup(
    Month(DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, GetDate())),
    Fields!MonthID.Value,
    Fields!Name.Value,
    "DataSet1")
```

This should calculate a number for last month, then look for a match in DataSet1.

Comment: what about scoping the lookup value to a group?  Is that possible?

Comment: What about earlier versions of SSRS? How would you achieve the same functionality? Custom code?

Answer (score 3):

In this example I have a tablix with Statecode and name as below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zTVE.png)

Suppose you want to display the name of state of CA, write an expression as -

```html
=Lookup(
   "CA" ,
   Fields!StateCode.Value,
   Fields!StateName.Value,
   "ReportData"
)
```

This will return 'California' in the text box

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this post while trying to solve a similar problem but with columns of double data type. Not sure why but SSRS did not want to return my first row using LOOKUP in combination with ROW_NUMBER in SQL(If someone can solve that all the better). I ended up using a SUM(IIF) instead. Hopefully, this is useful for someone else.

```
 =Sum(IIF(Fields!RowNum.Value=1,CDBL(Fields!MyNumericColumn.Value),CDBL(0)))
```

Note: If SSRS complains about data types, just cast both parts of the IIF to the desired data type.