# SSRS check if there was an entry yesterday with IIF expression

Tags: date, reporting-services, expression, reporting, iif

I have a problem with an IIF expression in SSRS. 
I'm creating a report for seeing who arrives to work late, we have 4 shifts. 
I'm trying to get false positives out of the report (e.g. someone goes back in after his/her shift has ended, and they are automatically counted as someone who is late for the next shift)

Everything works except for the night shift(the IIF for it is inside the first shift), which starts the previous night. 
i want the code to check if there is already an entry the previous night within the specified timeframe, if there is, than show the new "late" time as 0. 
All the other shifts are functional.

so what i have is

```
=CInt(IIF(
(Format(Fields!Aeg.Value,"HH")="06")
AND (Format(Fields!Aeg.Value,"mm")>"00")
AND (Fields!UksID.Value=14),IIF(CInt((Format(Fields!Aeg.Value, "dd"))-1)
AND(Format(Fields!Aeg.Value, "HH")>="22"),"0",(Format(Fields!Aeg.Value,"mm")))
,(IIF((Format(Fields!Aeg.Value,"HH")="08")
AND (Format(Fields!Aeg.Value,"mm")>"00")
AND (Fields!UksID.Value=14),IIF(Min(Format(Fields!Aeg.Value,"HH")<="8"),"0", 
(Format(Fields!Aeg.Value,"mm")), ...
```

...etc

where "Aeg" is the database field for the logged time
and "UksID" is a filter for the door

Help appreciated.

I've done a few edits according to your suggestion @tezzo,
i added

```
Public Function CheckDate(ByVal dateFromField As DateTime) As Boolean

Dim dateChecked As DateTime
dateChecked = DateAdd("d", -1, dateFromField)

Dim hourCheck As Integer
hourCheck = Hour(dateChecked)       

If hourCheck >= 22 Then 
Return True
   Else 
Return False
   End If

End Function
```

But it's checking for excactly 24 hours ago. 
how can i get it to take the Max value from that day 
`Max(Hour(dateChecked))` gives "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Max' accepts this number of arguments. (rsCompilerErrorInCode)"

Answer (score 0):

The error is here: `CInt((Format(Fields!Aeg.Value, "dd")) - 1)`

I think you can use a function that accept your `Aeg.Value`, verify if exists a record at `DateAdd(Day, -1, Aeg.Value)` with `HH > 22` and return a `Boolean`.

Check this link on how to [add code to a report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156028.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @tezzo
i think this is in the right direction. 
but it doesn't seem to fix the problem. 

If I create a new test field for the `DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Fields!Aeg.Value` i get the right result. I tried to get the hour out of with `Hour()` and `Format()` seems to work. I tried `Format("dd.HH")` to verify the date. date was ok. 
But whenever i add this to the entire formula, it starts to check for today again. 

Also, are there two different expressions for collapsed and expanded tablixes?

How do you mean to return a boolean? with custom code?

Comment: I suggested a custom function because I think you have the previous night data on another record of your table. In this case, if you have a date value in Fields!Aeg.Value (i.e. 2014/09/18) you have to check if there is ANOTHER record with date 2014/09/17 and HH > 22.

Comment: I tried but the "Custom functions" is a bit much for me right now. 

Could there be another way to categorize them into 4 fixed time shifts and then derive the deviation from the shift start time?

the LoggedTime is a `DATETIME` field in the query and the range is selected through `WHERE Events.LoggedTime BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate +1`. The default value for both of the parameters in the Report is the function `=Today` The `@endDate +1` is so that it actually includes the selected `@endDate` date.

Comment: sorry, but using Reporting Services I can't imagine another solution other than using custom code if the data you need are on different records. if you don't want use custom code try solving it in you SQL query.

Comment: Hi, @tezzo, can you take a look at my edit in the post?

Comment: In your edit you're simply creating a date. To find a record I think you can use Lookup function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004672/ssrs-get-values-from-a-particular-row-of-dataset